Bank robbery comedy with tunnel
A black and white comedy with sound. It was either French or Italian. Believe it was French. Setting was set to the 1900s, I guess 1930+, perhaps late fifties early sixties. Believe it was a contemporary film.
If I recall this correctly; It was about a family that for some reason was in money trouble. There was a bank robbery where they dug a tunnel from beneath their apartment to the city bank. This was the main plot, (IIRC). From what I remember the entire family, or at least some of them was in on it, but I might be getting that wrong. One of the issues was the noise made by either tools, explosives or the like that made for some interaction with the police. For some reason I also seem to remember they had some dinner (red-vine + pasta), and believe one of the visits from police was during the meal.

Sounds like a film with  Louis de Funès: Faites sauter la banque!
The English Wikipedia article don't tell the story, but the French and German articles tells a bit of the story.
I found also an English extract:

A modest shopkeeper, Victor Garnier, hands over his hard-earned
  savings to the director of the bank opposite his shop, to invest in
  shares in an oil company. A big mistake. When the shares become
  worthless, Garnier is determined to have his revenge and get back his
  money. With the help of his family, he plans to dig a tunnel from the
  cellar beneath his shop into the bank vault. Needless to say, nothing
  goes quite as planned…

IMDB has also an extract:

Shopkeeper Victor Garnier has naively invested his family's life
  savings in an African mine, on his banker's recommendation. When the
  mine is nationalized, rendering the stock worthless, he considers
  himself shamelessly robbed by the bank; it seems only fair to him to
  return the 'favor' and rob the bank, teaming up with the whole family
  as they were all duped. Even for professionals such an enterprise -he
  decides to dig a tunnel- is quite demanding, but for simple commoners
  it's daunting, as they also have their personal downsides; thus
  Victor's wife has a most unwelcome tendency to blurt out the truth,
  even to the grumpy local copper: a crazy risk when you need to keep a
  criminal plan secret


Ah yes. The plot sounded vaguely familiar. Had a look at this clip on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMbS7ecH5Io , and it has to be the one. It has the same energy, and I also recalled some of the scenes in the clip when I saw them. Thanks a bunch!
